# Object type array elements php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I stored some values in `db` using `json_encode`.Now on fetching i got values like this `["ab","cd"]`.I have tried by `exploding`,`json_encode` and then decode.But nothing works.some of tried code is below

```
$array = "["ab","cd"]";
$value = (array)$array;

//-------------
$array = (array) $array;
// get_object_vars
$array = get_object_vars($object);
print_r($array);
```

when i loop directly on array i didn't get any values.Thanks for any help in advance.
on this i got like this :

```
var_dump(json_decode($object));
print_r($object);
```

OUTPUT :

```
NULL ["MKD","KD3"]
```

Comment: `$array = json_decode('["ab","cd"]');`

Comment: @RobbieAverill thanks but you can check my question that after decoding i get null.Have look now on my question

Comment: Please post a realistic example of your `$array` value (`var_dump($array)`). What you've posted has syntax errors so it's not much use.

Comment: @RobbieAverill May be but the print r showing the complete data.issue is with jscon decode.its inside variable so if i echo it print like ['abc','dde'].as for error concern i didn't get any error on log

Comment: I think i have to go and use str replace method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your question, I think you are looking for [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode).

```
$json_encoded_str = '["ab","cd"]';

// Will return an array of elements in your string  
var_dump(json_decode($json_encoded_str));
```

The result would be

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> string(2) "ab"
    [1]=> string(2) "cd"
}
```

Comment: thanks for your message but when i try like that i got this reponse.check my question

Comment: It seems your object is not of type String. Try `var_dump($object);` and see if you get something like `string(13) "["MKD","KD3"]" `. If not, your $object is not json encoded.

Comment: when i var dump the value it prints like this `string(33) "["MKD","KD3"]"`

Comment: And when try with jsond_deconde it prints null.

Comment: i think its db issue.Its inside the db values is `[&quot;MKD&quot;,&quot;KD3&quot;]`

Comment: All you need to do is the following, then:
`$object = '[&quot;MKD&quot;,&quot;KD3&quot;]';
$obj_new = str_replace('&quot;','"', $object);
var_dump(json_decode($obj_new));`
I hope it helps.